# Correct behavior of libpq's PQexecPrepared and SQL EXECUTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, prepared-statement

It looks like with postgres, there are two ways to prepare and execute prepared statements. You can use the functions [`PQprepare`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/08ea7a2291db21a618d19d612c8060cda68f1892/src/interfaces/libpq/fe-exec.c#L1929) and [`PQexecPrepared`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/08ea7a2291db21a618d19d612c8060cda68f1892/src/interfaces/libpq/fe-exec.c#L1952) directly from `libpq`; or you can issue SQL statements: `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`. The statement names are the same across either method so you can use `PQPrepare` to prepare a statement and then execute it by issuing an `EXECUTE` query (or use a `PREPARE` query and then execute it with `PQexecPrepared`).

So the two approaches (library functions vs SQL queries) are equivalent. However, it looks like when you use `PQexecPrepared`, the `query` column of `pg_stat_activity` is the underlying prepared statement with placeholders. So something like:

```
SELECT * from users where name in ($1, $2, $3);
```

But when you use an `EXECUTE` query, `pg_stat_activity` contains the SQL of the `EXECUTE`, like:

```
EXECUTE user_query('joe', 'bob', 'sally');
```

#### Questions

1. Is there a way to get the same output for the two different ways of executing prepared statements?
2. Is there a way to see both the query, and the bound parameters when executing prepared statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that both ways to execute a prepared statement do the same thing under the hood, but since they are called in different ways on the SQL level, they look different in `pg_stat_activity`. There is no way to change that.

To get the statement *and* the parameters you must resort to the log file.

In the case of `PQexecPrepared`, you will see the statement as a `LOG` message and the parameters as its `DETAIL` if you turn on statement logging.

With `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`, you have no choice but to find the `PREPARE` earlier in the session (both have the same session identifier, that is `%c` in `log_line_prefix`).